# How to create a browser instance (pupeeteer) with firebase and use it in my app (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, puppeteer

I created a firebase project. This communicates with a mobile application (node.js). As part of this project I want to use pupeeteer.

I have no problem launching functions using pupeeteer in firebase.

The problem is that I want to make the user perform actions. So I have to display the web page (pupeeteer) in the application via a browser generated by the server (with a firebase function?)?

However I have no idea how to launch a browser instance in the background and close it at the end of processing?

Can you help me ? Is this the right solution?

[image]

I want to use this :

This library does 2 things:

Download the chromium binaries and launch a Chromium process.
Connect to this process with Websocket and send json commands to control the browser.
Due to limitations on mobile platforms (iOS and Android), it is not possible to launch an external Chromium process on iOS and Android. So, step 1) does not work on mobile.

You can still use puppeteer-dart on Flutter either with:

Flutter on Desktop (macOS, windows, Linux)
Flutter on mobile BUT with the actual Chrome instance running on a server and accessed from the mobile app using puppeteer.connect
The pub.dev website reports that this library works with Android and iOS. The supported platform list is detected automatically and can't be manually modified to express the current limitations